# How do I scrape a 'td' in web scraping

Tags: python

I am learning web scraping and I'm scraping in this following website: [ivmp servers](https://www.game-state.com/index.php?game=ivmp). I have trouble with scraping the number of players in the server, can someone help me? I will send the code of what I've done so far

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.game-state.com/index.php?game=ivmp').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

players = soup.find('table')

summary = players.find('div', class_ ='players')
print(summary)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: We shall assume that `having troubles` threw an error of some kind?  Can you post or elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the page you provided, i can assume that the table you want to extract information from is the one with server names and ip adresses. 
There are actually 4 "table" element on this page.

Luckily for you, this table has an id (serverlist). You can easily find it with right click > inspect on Chrome

```
players = soup.select_one('table#serverlist')
```

Now you want to get the td.
You can print all of them using :

```
for td in players.select("td"):
    print(td)
```

Or you can select the one you are interested in :

```
players.select("td.hostname")
```

for example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of the page, there are a few table cells (td) with the class "players", it looks like two of them are for sorting the table, so we'll assume you don't want those.

In order to extract the one(s) you do want, I would first query for all the td elements with the class "players", and then loop through them adding only the ones we do want to an array.

Something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.game-state.com/index.php?game=ivmp').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

players = soup.find_all('td', class_='players')

summary = []

for cell in players:
    # Exclude the cells which are for sorting
    if cell.get_text() != 'Players':
        summary.append(cell.get_text())

print(summary)
```